# how to make mongo-express show all db?

Tags: mongodb

here is my mongo-express config, when i login http://192.168.1.104:8081, it only shows the **admin db**, i want it to **show all db**. i had ran this command before

```
use admin

db.createUser(
{
user: "root",
pwd: "password",
roles: [ "root" ]
}
)
```

config file:

```
'use strict';

var url = require('url');

if (typeof process.env.MONGODB_PORT === 'string') {
  var mongoConnection = url.parse(process.env.MONGODB_PORT);
  process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER = mongoConnection.hostname;
  process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT = mongoConnection.port;
}

module.exports = {
  mongodb: {
    server: process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT || 27017,

    //autoReconnect: automatically reconnect if connection is lost
    autoReconnect: true,
    //poolSize: size of connection pool (number of connections to use)
    poolSize: 4,
    //set admin to true if you want to turn on admin features
    //if admin is true, the auth list below will be ignored
    //if admin is true, you will need to enter an admin username/password below (if it is needed)
    admin: true,


    // >>>>  If you are using regular accounts, fill out auth details in the section below
    // >>>>  If you have admin auth, leave this section empty and skip to the next section
    auth: [
      /*
       * Add the the name, the username, and the password of the databases you want to connect to
       * Add as many databases as you want!
      {
        database: 'test',
        username: 'user',
        password: 'pass'
      }
      */
      ],


    //  >>>>  If you are using an admin mongodb account, or no admin account exists, fill out section below
    //  >>>>  Using an admin account allows you to view and edit all databases, and view stats

    //leave username and password empty if no admin account exists
    adminUsername: process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME || '',
    adminPassword: process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD || '',
    //whitelist: hide all databases except the ones in this list  (empty list for no whitelist)
    whitelist: [],
    //blacklist: hide databases listed in the blacklist (empty list for no blacklist)
    blacklist: []
  },

  site: {
    host: '192.168.1.104',
    port: 8081,
    cookieSecret: process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_COOKIESECRET || 'cookiesecret',
    sessionSecret: process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_SESSIONSECRET || 'sessionsecret',
    cookieKeyName: 'mongo-express',
    sslEnabled: process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_ENABLED || false,
    sslCert: process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_CRT_PATH || '',
    sslKey: process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_KEY_PATH || ''
  },

  //set useBasicAuth to true if you want to authehticate mongo-express loggins
  //if admin is false, the basicAuthInfo list below will be ignored
  //this will be true unless ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME is set and is the empty string
  useBasicAuth: process.env.ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME !== '',

  basicAuth: {
    username: process.env.ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME || 'root',
    password: process.env.ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD || 'password'
  },

  options: {
    //documentsPerPage: how many documents you want to see at once in collection view
    documentsPerPage: 10,
    //editorTheme: Name of the theme you want to use for displaying documents
    //See http://codemirror.net/demo/theme.html for all examples
    editorTheme: process.env.ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME || 'rubyblue',

    //The options below aren't being used yet

    //cmdType: the type of command line you want mongo express to run
    //values: eval, subprocess
    //  eval - uses db.eval. commands block, so only use this if you have to
    //  subprocess - spawns a mongo command line as a subprocess and pipes output to mongo express
    cmdType: 'eval',
    //subprocessTimeout: number of seconds of non-interaction before a subprocess is shut down
    subprocessTimeout: 300,
    //readOnly: if readOnly is true, components of writing are not visible.
    readOnly: false
  },

  // Specify the default keyname that should be picked from a document to display in collections list.
  // Keynames can be specified for every database and collection.
  // If no keyname is specified, it defalts to '_id', which is a mandatory feild.
  // For Example :
  // defaultKeyNames{
  //   "world_db":{  //Database Name
  //     "continent":"cont_name", // collection:feild
  //     "country":"country_name",
  //     "city":"name"
  //   }
  // }
  defaultKeyNames: {

  }
};
```

***Remarks:***
in above config, 
      basicAuth: {
        username: process.env.ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME || 'root',
        password: process.env.ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD || 'password'
      },

i changed the username, password to root and password repectively, when i access http://192.168.1.104:8081 , i need to enter root and password in http auth prompt so as i entering the mongo-express web panel.

Answer (score 6):

This is my first answer on StackOverflow, but hopefully it's helpful.

Issue in your case seems to be database authentication defined in config.js.
You need to pass the db credentials through "auth" section and not through "basicAuth".
Also, once you correct the config.js file, start the mongo-express with `-a` switch, i.e. -> `cd YOUR_PATH/node_modules/mongo-express/ && node app.js -a`

Corrected section of config.js :

```
admin: true,


// >>>>  If you are using regular accounts, fill out auth details in the section below
// >>>>  If you have admin auth, leave this section empty and skip to the next section
auth: [
  /*
   * Add the the name, the username, and the password of the databases you want to connect to
   * Add as many databases as you want!
  {
    database: 'test',
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass'
  }
  */
  ],


//  >>>>  If you are using an admin mongodb account, or no admin account exists, fill out section below
//  >>>>  Using an admin account allows you to view and edit all databases, and view stats

//leave username and password empty if no admin account exists
adminUsername: process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME || 'root',
adminPassword: process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD || 'password',
```