# Mongo-Express not showing all DBs with root admin

Tags: mongodb, express

I am having a bit trouble setting up mongo-express with my local mongodb install. Basically, I created an admin user like this:

```
  db.createUser(
   {
       user: "admin", 
       pwd: "abc123", 
       roles:["root"]
   })
```

And in mongo-express's config.js I specified this account for the authentication. Running `mongo-express -u "admin" -p "abc123" -d "admin"` works, and opening the webview shows the admin database.

[image]

But that is the only DB it shows there, but I have more DBs within mongodb:

```
> show dbs
admin     0.000GB
local     0.000GB
test      0.112GB
```

I want the `test` DB to show up there as well, but I do not understand whats preventing mongo-express from displaying it. I do understand that authentication happens at DB level, but since the admin was created with `root` as role, mongo-express should be able to display all DBs, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found the problem:

Apparently one has to run 'mongo-express' with the '-a' flag when admin credentials are stored in the config.js and one wishes to let mongo-express access mongodb as admin.

This helped me: [how to make mongo-express show all db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950334/how-to-make-mongo-express-show-all-db)